How can I connect g signals directly?
I can connect a signal with g_signal_connect(entry, "icon-press", (GCallback)show_input, NULL); and handle it with
static void show_input(GtkEntry *entry, GtkEntryIconPosition position, gpointer show)
{
    if(show) gtk_entry_set_visibility((GtkEntry *)entry, TRUE);
    else(gtk_entry_set_visibility((GtkEntry *)entry, FALSE);
}

Is it possible to call functions directly without calling a callback. I ask because my callback function doesn't have many lines so I would like an alternative in which I execute a gtk api fuction directly
like
g_signal_connect(entry, "icon-press", gtk_entry_set_visibility, FALSE);
Using g_signal_connect will not work because of its parameter requirements, are there equivalent functions other than g_sinal_connect

Well, C doesn't have lambdas (at least not as of C24). And I see nothing in the documentation either. So the answer is (probably) no.

"Is it possible to call functions directly since the callback doesn't have many lines like" -- it's not understandable. You can set a handler on an event that you want ("icon-press" for example), all the extra data is delivered with userdata pointer (the final arg of signal-handlers). By its gist Gsignal API callbacks are polymorphic  depending on an instanse and events.

@yvs2014 my callback function was too short(2 lines of code) i was wondering if I could connect the signals any other way than using g_signal_connect

"my callback function was too short(2 lines of code)" -- write so many lines as you want, what's a real obstacle that you faced?

Well you can subclass the GtkEntry, and then you can probably overwrite the default handler for the signal, "icon-pressed". But thats a whole lot more work than calling g_signal_connect. I would advice to use GTK_ENTRY() to cast and G_CALLBACK() instead. Especially the first might be helpful when the entry isn't a GtkEntry*. In your example the gpointer show is always false based on the NULL in the call of g_signal_connect.

Experiment with g_object_bind_property, from the docs: "Creates a binding between source_property on source and target_property on target". See if the object can be source and target at the same time.
